# Hasse Diagram multiple choice. Upper/lower bound and maximal/minimal.

Tags: solution-verification, order-theory, upper-lower-bounds

[image]

Hi, this is one of the questions from my Discrete Mathematics exam that I got wrong. I believe I answered 2 since I did not see the "not" in the question.

Which of the following statements is true?

1: The greatest lower bound of S = {c,d} lies outside S.

- False. e and f are not comparable so neither can be the greatest lower bound element of S.

2: e and b are not comparable.

- False. e and b are comparable through c. Since e < c and c < b then e < b.

3: the set {c,d} has maximal element b and minimal element f

- True. b is greater than c and d and there is no comparable element greater than b. f is lower than c and d and there is no comparable element lower than f.

4: the least upper bound of {c,d} are the elements a and b.

- False. a and b are not comparable so neither can be the least upper bound.

In question 1 my answer is False but I am unsure. Does lower bound elements of a subset of a poset have to be related to every element of the subset? if so that would mean f is the only lower bound of {c,d} and therefore also the greatest lower bound element and outside of S so 1 would be true?

In question 3 my answer is True but again I am not sure. When asked this way does that mean only from the elements inside of S in which case False because c and d are not comparable?

Comment: Yes, $f$ is the greatest lower bound of $\{c,d\}$ (its only lower bound). In $\{c,d\}$, both elements are maximal and minimal ($b$ is not maximal in the set since it doesn't belong to it). Similar to the first, the least upper bound of $\{c,d\}$ is $b$ (notice $a$ is not an upper bound of $d$).